# Matching multiple similar strings in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, n-gram

So here is a situation:

I need to find a way to match 2 similar strings, for example:

a - `SAMSUNG Galaxy S5 White`

b - `Mobile phone SAMSUNG GALAXY S5 WHITE`

I have the string `a` in database field, now I have and equivalent string coming from outside source. So obviously this is, the same product, but if I do straight up search for title field, the search will not yield the desired results.

Any ideas how I could make a lookup, that will look for similar strings? 
Maybe break up the string into tokens? Is there any query I write that will look according to those tokens? Would the ngram lookup feature introduced in MySQL 5.7.6 would be useful in this scenario?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at MySQL's `LOCATE()`

Answer (score 1):

Using `LIKE` as is being described in other answers won't work, because the text you're searching for is not a substring of what's in the database (given your example).  There are a couple of ways to handle this, depending on your situation.

If you know in advance the different varying strings that you might be supplied with, you can create another table `aliases` to store those strings and link them to your primary table with a foreign key.

If you don't know them in advance, perhaps because they are user-supplied search terms, then you would need to dynamically build a query that will break up the terms and search for them individually, like this:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM table
 WHERE field LIKE '%Mobile%'
    OR field LIKE '%phone%'
    OR field LIKE '%SAMSUNG%'
    OR field LIKE '%GALAXY%'
    OR field LIKE '%S5%'
    OR field LIKE '%WHITE%'
```

While something like this will find the correct result, it may also return false positives (i.e. anything with the word "white" or "phone" is also returned), so this is probably not the way to go.

If you're using MyISAM tables with MySQL <= 5.5, or MyISAM or InnoDB tables with MySQL >= 5.6, you can use full-text searches and match/against, like this:

```
SELECT MATCH( field ) AGAINST ( 'Mobile', 'phone', 'SAMSUNG', 'GALAXY', 'S5', 'WHITE' ) as relevance
  FROM table
 WHERE MATCH( field ) AGAINST ( 'Mobile', 'phone', 'SAMSUNG', 'GALAXY', 'S5', 'WHITE' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

This will not only find the rows that match, but it will sort them by relevance (i.e. how many match).  You could limit this to 1 row if you knew that the most relevant match was the correct one, or you could display a list of choices beginning with the most relevant.

Check out the documentation page for [Full-Text Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE %pattern%;
```

This will select from you're column name like you're value. The wildcard `%` is a  substitute for zero or more characters. Here is some [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) of `like`

Answer (score 0):

Checking 'Like' may be be helpful [mysql Like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE %key%;
```

You'll get the result that the column_name contains key.